# How to export directory files in CSV file without Mode, LastWrite etc using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Using `dir > list.csv` will create the list I need in whichever directory im in, but it includes unnecessary information as well. It has a column for the Mode, LastWriteTime, LengthName etc which I then have to manually delete, because I'm using OpenOffice and need the list of files to compose a new CSV which I'm then going to import into a database.

I would like to use a switch that allow me to solely export the file name in CSV not the other items. Is this possible with a useful command or switch or would it involve scripting?

Comment: others have mentioned expanding the `.Name` property & sending that to a plain text file [some named with `.csv`, but still plain text]. if you actually want a proper CSV file, you  can use >>> `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDIr -File | Select-Object -Property Name | Export-CSV -LIteralPath $DestFIleName -NoTypeInformation`  <<< that will give you a standard CSV formatted file. [*grin*]

Comment: There's not really any point to a CSV file with only one column, though...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name > list.txt
```

The `list.txt` will contain the filename of each file.

(Note that CSV means "comma-separated values" and is a delimited file format. A plain list of names really isn't a CSV file.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name > test.csv 
(Get-Content test.csv) -join ',' | Set-Content test.csv
```

Comment: That would generate a list of names and isn't really a CSV file. I think you mean `> list.txt` or `| Out-File list.txt`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart You're right. My apologies. I updated the code with lines to convert it to a proper CSV. Thank you.

Comment: Your added lines don't make sense - do you mean you want to create a single-column CSV file? (Why do that when you can just use the input file directly?)